# Chunk overhead in the MongoDb gridfs when using the official C# driver to store small files

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver, gridfs

GridFs has a default chunksize of 256 kb, but if I store a lot of small 6 kb files, would I then incur a 250 kb overhead of reserved but unused discspace pr file, or will GridFs pack small files in the same chunk? (I am aware that there is some additional overhead for metadata).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The same question was asked and answered on the [mongodb-user group on Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!searchin/mongodb-user/gridfs/mongodb-user/H6gDl69o_o0/H211eJwQmMYJ).

> The last chunk of a GridFS file is only as large as it needs to be, so there won't be much overhead.
>
> In your example, a 6kb file would be stored as a single 6kb chunk (plus metadata).

Comment: But how come that mongo shell shows chunksize 262144 for a file of 15,2 kb? :
> db.fs.files.find().pretty()
    {
    "_id" : ObjectId("4f7aea4d8f0ddc187c435718"),
    "filename" : "logo.png",
    "length" : 15624,
    "chunkSize" : 262144,
    "uploadDate" : ISODate("2012-04-03T12:17:17.196Z"),
    "md5" : "5b1a277095f6535c9f7353c3a3d320f0"
    }

Comment: Because that's the chunk size that was used when this file was uploaded. If you actually went and looked at the one and only chunk you would find that its size is 15.2KB.